# Reading files difference during compile and running from jar file

Tags: java, file, maven-3

I am trying to write and read from files. Can any one explain what is it that is making things different.

I take properties from properties files and I have paths to different files that I use in my application.

Issue is that the behaviour of my application changes with respect to when this code is being run. For example, If I compile the code through maven and the JUnit tests are run, the test.properties that is in the resources folder is not taken i have to put it in the root of my project for it to work. Secondly, the code that works for some file that I want to copy from one folder or witihin the jar are two different sets of code. So doing a JUnit test method for this operation is useless as I can make it work in test case using a different way and make it work from a jar in another.

my test.properties has :

```
cssFileLocation =src/main/resources/all.css
```

my production.properties has (which is OK as the files in the resources folder are moved to root of Jar):

```
cssFileLocation=all.css
```

My code is the below method, that is supposed to move the css file into an external directory under `/static/all.css`:

```
 public static void copyCSS(String newCSSTargetLocation, String cssFileLocation) {
        File source = null;
        String line = "";
        String cssString = null;
        source = new File(cssFileLocation);

        File dest = new File(newCSSTargetLocation + "/static/all.css");
        logger.debug("Absoulte path of css file  : " + source.getAbsolutePath());
        /**
         * The Block below works when executing the jar
         */
        InputStream input;
        input = GeoUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(cssFileLocation);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));) {
            line = "";

            if (null == reader) {
                logger.debug("reader  is null");
            }

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb = sb.append(line);
                sb = sb.append("\n");
            }

            cssString = new String(sb);

        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
            logger.error("Exception in Buffered reader writer ....");
            ex.printStackTrace();


        }

        /**
         * This Block works when doing compile and tests are run through
         * Surefire
         */
        try {
            cssString = FileUtils.readFileToString(source, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occured when reading through new File " + cssFileLocation);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (null == dest) {
            logger.debug("destination file is a null file Cannot proceed to create all.css in " + newCSSTargetLocation);
        } else {
            logger.debug(" dest not null " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
             try {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(dest, cssString, "UTF-8");
            logger.debug(" all.css created to new location  Through File Utils  >>" + dest.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Exception occured when writing to  " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }


    }
```

The error that comes when I run my test method that calls this method during compile (mvn clean install)

```
ERROR [main] (GeoUtils.java:673) - Exception in Buffered reader writer ....
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
        at com.sarm.lonelyplanet.common.GeoUtils.copyCSS(GeoUtils.java:658)
        at com.sarm.lonelyplanet.common.GeoUtilsTest.testCopyCSS(GeoUtilsTest.java:207)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how Maven works.

When it compile the project, it copies the contents of `src/main/resources` to `target/classes`. `target/classes` is part of the classpath when running a unit test. It's also what goes into the jar that you put in the classpath in your production application.

So, whether you're executing a test or running in production, a file `all.css` that is in `src/main/resources` in your project ends up at the root of the classpath. So all you need to load this file is

```
SomeClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("all.css");
```

The same code, and the same path, will work fine in your tests, and in production. Your should not use file IO to read files that are in src/main/resources. These are not really files. They are resources intended to be loaded by the classloader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in essence, I should not use Input stream or new File(relativepathtofilename) when trying to access jar contents. I should use getResourecAsStream() I really liked the FileUtils.readFileToString(File) method it was simple and very easy to use. But when i compiled the code that worked in Jar form didnt work either. FileUtils.readFiletoString worked fine with a different relative path.